# Automatically save deleted lines to a new file?

Tags: buffers, cut-copy-paste

I have a to do list that I manage in vim. I want to keep track of things I remove from the list.

After I type `dd` to delete a line, I want to write this line to a different file.

I only want this behavior when I am in my todo list, not other files. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well.

You probably should map `dd` to

1. append current line to some file
2. do normal `dd` aftewards

```
nnoremap dd :.write! >> ~/different_file<CR>dd
```

`write` command can append a `range` to a specified file if `>>` is supplied.
Here `.` is the range of "current line".

To make it only available for a specified buffer you should create a mapping with `<buffer>` argument (`:h :map-local`):

```
nnoremap <buffer> dd :.write! >> ~/different_file<CR>dd
```

To properly apply this mapping to a specific buffer you will have to use autocommand:

```
augroup TODO | au!
    au BufRead,BufNew todo.txt nnoremap <buffer> dd :.write! >> ~/different_file<CR>dd
augroup END
```

Here you create an autogroup, clear it (needed in case you re-source your vimrc) and add autocommand for 2 events: `BufRead` and `BufNew` for a buffer named `todo.txt`.

Now if you open or create a buffer named `todo.txt` buffer local mapping would be only available in this buffer.